# Save to DB in model method or controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to wrap my head around MVC and how to use it. I would appreciate any help with my question.

I created a model with EF DB First. My application only adds data to the DB. So question is, where should I be conducting the saving to the DB? In my controller or in a method that lives within partial class of my model?

Comment: it should be in the model, or from classes/methods called from the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical introductory book to MVC they present a basic Data-Entry app with  a simple data model, e.g: a class with personal data to enter by the user,
a HomeController with Index view called by an ViewResult method called Index  and a Data entry view that uses Html helpers to create a form with a set of fields.

That view will be handled by a pair of  ViewResult methods in the same HomeController , one decorated with [HttpGet], that one presents the view with the editable form to the user , and the other is decorated with [HttpPost] , that one will receive and bind the data from the edited view.

THe binding will be done by a component of MVC called the modelBinder and in that ViewResult method.
There you will call to your EF's DbContext  to save the data.
Please keep in mind that this direct call to DbContext is made in the context of a really simple "learning app" , the correct way to do it is to create a Data manipulation layer with it's own project and create a service that will be  instantiated by IoC library like Unity or Ninject. Hope it helps.